# Как читать и вывести информацию с json?

Tags: php, json

Как вывести сгруппированные данные из json, только из

```
rubrics / championships / 4 / games /
```

[listGamesByDate.json](https://matchtv.ru/stats/Api/listGamesByDate.json)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получилось вывести только полностью весь json

```
$f_json = 'https://matchtv.ru/stats/Api/listGamesByDate.json';
$json = file_get_contents("$f_json");   

echo $json;
```

Comment: `json_decode($json, true)` сделайте, и будет у вас массив. с массивами то умеете работать?

Comment: `$obj = json_decode($json,true);` это писал, дальше тяжко

Answer (score 0):

По крайней мере на текущий день подойдет:

```
$url = 'https://matchtv.ru/stats/Api/listGamesByDate.json';
$content = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($content, true);

$day = reset($data);

$games = $day['rubrics'][2]['championships'][4]['games'];
print_r($games);
```

Comment: Как быть с днём?

Comment: подправил ответ

Comment: А дальше как? https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/59f54887-5900-4ca2-b7e0-6adc97abc06a.png

Comment: А дальше почитать как работать с массивами http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php